# Find the equation of parabola tangent to a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

I know how to find the equation of the line tangent to a parabola through a certain point. But how do I find the equation of the parabola from the point and the tangent line? For example, how do I find the equation of the parabola that is tangent to the line $x+y-15=0$ at the point $(12,3)$?

Comment: Solve for $y$, then integrate.  Then modify the resulting constant $C$ to correspond to the given tangent.  What else have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many parabolas with a given tangent line at a specific point on the line. For example, I’m sure you can find more than one parabola tangent to the line $y=0$ at the point $(0,0)$? The word “the” is tricky. It implicitly suggests there is only one such thing, but in this case, you can’t say “the” parabola, because there is more than one. A point and a slope determine a line, but a point and a slope do not determine a parabola.

Comment: Here are a few: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=plot+15+-+x%2C+x%5E2+-+25+x+%2B+159%2C+2+x%5E2+-+49+x+%2B+303%2C+-x%5E2+%2B+23+x+-+129+from+11+to+13&oq=plot+15+-+x%2C+x%5E2+-+25+x+%2B+159%2C+2+x%5E2+-+49+x+%2B+303%2C+-x%5E2+%2B+23+x+-+129+from+11+to+13

Comment: I also know that the axis of the parabola is parallel to the X axis. Does that help?

Comment: No. There are still infinitely many different parabolas possible. For example, $x=y^2-7y+24$ and $x=2y^2-13y+33$. If you know that the parabola is of the form $x=y^2+ax+b$, there is only one, but you need to know something other that what you’ve said.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming our parabola is symmetric about an axis parallel to the y axis:

$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$y'=2ax+b$$

Given $P(12,3)$ and $(x+y-15)=0 \implies y=-x+15 \implies m=-1$

$$3=a(12)^2+b(12)+c$$
$$-1=2a(12)+b$$

The last two equations express a relation between the constants. They are 2 linear equations in 3 unknowns meaning there are an infinite number of solutions.

Allowing the axis of the parabola to tilt arbitrarily introduces alternative relations between a,b, and c.